# Getting runtime path to a package in Bazel toolchain configuration files

Tags: bazel, starlark

What is the best way to refer to an external package's path in any arbitrary files processed by Bazel?

I'm trying to understand how Bazel preprocesses BUILD and .bzl files. I see instances where strings contain calls to package() and I am wondering how it works (and could not find any relevant documentation). Here is an example of this:

I have a toolchain which BUILD file contains the following expression :

```py
cc_toolchain_config(
    name = "cc-toolchain-config",
    abi_libc_version = "glibc_" + host_gcc8_bundle()["pkg_version"]["glibc"],
    abi_version = "gcc-" + host_gcc8_bundle()["version"],
    compiler = "gcc-" + host_gcc8_bundle()["version"],
    cpu = "x86_64",
    cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
        "%package(@host_gcc8_toolchain//include/c++/8)%",
        "%package(@host_gcc8_toolchain//lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed)%",
        "%package(@host_gcc8_kernel_headers//include)%",
        "%package(@host_gcc8_glibc//include)%",
    ],
    host_system_name = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
    target_libc = "glibc_" + host_gcc8_bundle()["pkg_version"]["glibc"],
    target_system_name = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
    toolchain_identifier = "host_linux_gcc8",
)
```

From my understanding, the `cxx_builtin_include_directories` defines a list of strings to serve as the `--sysroot` option passed to GCC as detailed in https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.23.0/skylark/lib/cc_common.html These strings are in the format `%sysroot%`.

Since `package(@host_gcc8_toolchain//include/c++/8)` for example, does not mean anything to GCC, bazel has to somehow expand this function to produce the actual path to the files included in the package before passing them to the compiler driver.

But how can it determine that this needs to be expanded and that it is not a regular string ? So how does Bazel preprocess the BUILD file ? Is it because of the `% ... %` pattern ? Where is this documented ?

is `"%package(@external_package//target)%"` a pattern that can be used elsewhere ? In any BUILD file ? Where do I find Bazel documentation showing how this works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These directives are expanded by [`cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_cc_toolchain_config_info) within the `cc_toolchain_config` rule implementation not any sort of preprocessing on the `BUILD` file (I.e., `"%package(@host_gcc8_glibc//include)%"` is literally passed into the `cc_toolchain_config` rule.) I'm not aware that these special expansions are completely documented anywhere but [the source](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/6d448136d13ddab92da8bb29ea6e8387821369d9:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcToolchainProviderHelper.java;l=309-329).